# Forcing a default class in emacs org-mode other than Article?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Looking for some help on how to set org-latex-default-class inside my .emacs file.

Currently I have to put this in my documents to switch out of article mode:

```
  #+:LaTex_CLASS: hitec
```

In the document file.  But I'd really like to eliminate it and juse make the default class that org-mode latex uses set to hitec.  Any help is really appreciated.

```lisp
(require 'org-latex)
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
             '("hitec"
             "\\documentclass{hitec}
               \\usepackage{graphicx}
               \\usepackage{graphicx}
               \\usepackage{hyperref}
               \\usepackage{parskip}
               \\usepackage{pstricks}
               \\usepackage{textcomp}
               \\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
               \\usepackage{listings}
               \\usepackage{fancyvrb}
               \\presetkeys{bclogo}{ombre=true,epBord=3,couleur = blue!15!white,couleurBord = red,arrondi = 0.2,logo=\bctrombone}{}
               \\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
               \\company{GIS / CME Group}
               [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
               [NO-PACKAGES]"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Comment: Why not use `customize-variable RET org-latex-default-class RET`?  Or just a simple `(setq org-…-class "hitec")`…

Answer (score 2):

`org-export-latex-classes` require `ox-latex.el` . Your code should be:

```
(require 'ox-latex)
(require 'org-latex)
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
             '("hitec"
             "\\documentclass{hitec}
               \\usepackage{graphicx}
               \\usepackage{graphicx}
               \\usepackage{hyperref}
               \\usepackage{parskip}
               \\usepackage{pstricks}
               \\usepackage{textcomp}
               \\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
               \\usepackage{listings}
               \\usepackage{fancyvrb}
               \\presetkeys{bclogo}{ombre=true,epBord=3,couleur = blue!15!white,couleurBord = red,arrondi = 0.2,logo=\bctrombone}{}
               \\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
               \\company{GIS / CME Group}
               [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
               [NO-PACKAGES]"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```